# How to include assets / resources in a Swift Package Manager library?

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I would like to ship my library using Apple's Swift Package Manager. However my lib includes a .bundle file with several strings translated in different languages.
Using cocoapods, I can include it using spec.resource. But in SwiftPM, I cannot do it. Any solution?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using Swift 5.3 it's finally possible to add localized resources

The Package initializer now has a `defaultLocalization` parameter which can be used for localization resources.

```swift
public init(
    name: String,
    defaultLocalization: LocalizationTag = nil, // New defaultLocalization parameter.
    pkgConfig: String? = nil,
    providers: [SystemPackageProvider]? = nil,
    products: [Product] = [],
    dependencies: [Dependency] = [],
    targets: [Target] = [],
    swiftLanguageVersions: [Int]? = nil,
    cLanguageStandard: CLanguageStandard? = nil,
    cxxLanguageStandard: CXXLanguageStandard? = nil
)
```

Let's say you have an `Icon.png` which you want to be localised for English and German speaking people.

The images should be included in `Resources/en.lproj/Icon.png` & `Resources/de.lproj/Icon.png`.

After you can reference them in your package like that:

```swift
let package = Package(
    name: "BestPackage",
    defaultLocalization: "en",
    targets: [
        .target(name: "BestTarget", resources: [
            .process("Resources/Icon.png"),
        ])
    ]
)
```

Please note `LocalizationTag` is a wrapper of [IETF Language Tag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IETF_language_tag).

Credits and input from [following proposals overview](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0278-package-manager-localized-resources.md), please check it for more details.

Comment: How would I access a resource within a Swift Package assuming the above is followed?  Ex: Parent app has a Swift package "ImageHelper" and I want to access a specific image resource within from the parent app, how is this done? Bundle.Something.path?

Answer (score 44):

The package manager does not yet have any definition for how resources will be bundled with targets. We are aware of the need for this, but don't yet have a concrete proposal for it. I filed https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2866 to ensure we have a bug tracking this.

Comment: There's now a draft proposal for this: https://forums.swift.org/t/draft-proposal-package-resources/2994

Comment: Slight typo above, draft proposal is https://forums.swift.org/t/draft-proposal-package-resources/29941

Comment: Looks like the proposal [passed](https://forums.swift.org/t/accepted-with-modifications-se-0271-package-manager-resources/31021) as [SE-0271](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0271-package-manager-resources.md). Still needs to be implemented though.

Comment: Update : It is coming for sure with Swift 5.3 released somewhere between May & September 2020. https://forums.swift.org/t/se-0271-package-manager-resources/30730/74

Answer (score 7):

starting on Swift 5.3, thanks to [SE-0271](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0271-package-manager-resources.md), you can add bundle resources on swift package manager by adding `resources` on your `.target` declaration.

example:

```
.target(
   name: "HelloWorldProgram",
   dependencies: [], 
   resources: [.process(Images), .process("README.md")]
)
```

if you want to learn more, I have written an article on [medium](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-add-resources-in-swift-package-manager-c437d44ec593), discussing this topic

Answer (score 5):

Due to framework bundles not being supported *yet*, the only way to provide bundle assets with an SPM target is through a Bundle. If you implement code in your framework to search for a particular bundle in your main project (supporting asset bundles), you can load resources from said bundle.

Example:

Access the bundled resources:

```
extension Bundle {
    static func myResourceBundle() throws -> Bundle {
        let bundles = Bundle.allBundles
        let bundlePaths = bundles.compactMap { $0.resourceURL?.appendingPathComponent("MyAssetBundle", isDirectory: false).appendingPathExtension("bundle") }
        
        guard let bundle = bundlePaths.compactMap({ Bundle(url: $0) }).first else {
            throw NSError(domain: "com.myframework", code: 404, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Missing resource bundle"])
        }
        return bundle
    }
}
```

Utilize the Bundled resources:

```
let bundle = try! Bundle.myResourceBundle()
return UIColor(named: "myColor", in: bundle, compatibleWith: nil)!
```

You can apply the same logic for all resource files, including but not limited to storyboards, xibs, images, colors, data blobs, and files of various extensions (json, txt, etc).

Note: Sometimes this makes sense, sometimes it doesn't. Determine use to own project's discretion. It would take very specific scenarios to justify separating Storyboards/Xibs into bundled assets.

Answer (score 3):

The solution I use for this is to build the data I need into a Swift object. To this end I have a shell script that will read an input file, base64 encode it, then write a Swift file that presents it as an InputStream. Then, when I want to add a data item to my Swift package, I run the script to read the file and write the output file. Of course the output file needs to be checked in so that the resource is available to those who use the project even if they do not have the script. (Typically I place my input files in a `Resources` directory and write the output to the `Sources` directory, but the script itself does not depend on that.)

I consider this a less than ideal solution, and am looking forward to when the package manager has this ability built in. But in the meantime, it is a workable solution.

The following example shows how it is used:

First, here is the script itself:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Read an input file, base64 encode it, then write an output swift file that will
# present it as an input stream.
#
# Usage: generate_resource_file.sh <inputfile> <outputfile> <streamName>
#
# The <streamName> is the name presented for the resulting InputStream. So, for example,
#   generate_resource_file.sh Resources/logo.png Sources/Logo.swift logoInputStream
# will generate a file Sources/Logo.swift that will contain a computed variable
# that will look like the following:
#   var logoInputStream: InputStream { ...blah...
#

set -e

if [ $# -ne 3 ]; then
    echo "Usage: generate_resource_file.sh <inputfile> <outputfile> <streamName>"
    exit -1
fi

inFile=$1
outFile=$2
streamName=$3

echo "Generating $outFile from $inFile"
echo "Stream name will be $streamName"

if [ ! -f "$inFile" ]; then
    echo "Could not read $inFile"
    exit -1
fi

echo "// This file is automatically generated by generate_resource_file.sh. DO NOT EDIT!" > "$outFile"
echo "" >> "$outFile"
echo "import Foundation" >> "$outFile"
echo "" >> "$outFile"
echo "fileprivate let encodedString = \"\"\"" >> "$outFile"
base64 -i "$inFile" >> "$outFile"
echo "\"\"\"" >> "$outFile"
echo "" >> "$outFile"
echo "var $streamName: InputStream {" >> "$outFile"
echo "    get {" >> "$outFile"
echo "        let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: encodedString)!" >> "$outFile"
echo "        return InputStream(data: decodedData)" >> "$outFile"
echo "    }" >> "$outFile"
echo "}" >> "$outFile"

echo "Rebuilt $outFile"
```

Then, given an input file `t.dat` shown here:

```
Hello World!
```

Running the command `generate_resource_file.sh t.dat HelloWorld.swift helloWorldInputStream` generates the following `HelloWorld.swift` file:

```
// This file is automatically generated by generate_resource_file.sh. DO NOT EDIT!

import Foundation

fileprivate let encodedString = """
SGVsbG8gV29ybGQhCgo=
"""

var helloWorldInputStream: InputStream {
    get {
        let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: encodedString)!
        return InputStream(data: decodedData)
    }
}
```

Comment: Now that Swift Package Manager supports this in a nicer framework, you should no longer use my solution (unless of course you have to support a legacy version for some reason). Instead you should use the solution posted by @bilalreffas.

Answer (score -1):

Important note:

Resources doesn't seem to be included in the Xcode project generated by

`swift package generate-xcodeproj`

But they are when you open the Package folder on Xcode (`xed .`) and then double click on the package to resolve dependencies.

I'm including a nice tutorial as well: https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-add-resources-in-swift-package-manager-c437d44ec593