# How can I add a demo app target to a Swift Package?

Tags: swift-package-manager

I'm looking to include a demo app with a Swift Package of custom controls that shows implementation demos for each of the controls. Is there a way that I can include this in the Swift Package (and also develop/test the controls directly inside the package this way)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What kind of app? SwiftPM only directly supports macOS/Linux executables.

If you want an iOS/tvOS/watchOS one you will need an Xcode project that links using a relative path to find your package. This is done by creating the example app and dragging the Package's containing directory into the Xcode project. You can then link the library. If you put this example app in the repo with the package then it will be distributed along with anyone who clones the package.

One important thing I have noticed (which is almost certainly a bug in Xcode) when doing this myself is that the `Package.swift` and `Example.xcodeproj` cannot be in the same directory. You have to nest the Xcode project into another directory or it will have issues building/linking a lot of the time. So if you run into any issues With what I have suggested also try this bandaid.

I have created an example on GitHub [here](https://github.com/bscothern/ExampleAppForSwiftPackage) that works for Xcode 11.3.

Comment: Yeah was looking to have a macOS demo but iOS could work. Maybe it was just an Xcode bug because I was also seeing something similar. Would you mind providing your Package.swift file?

Comment: Example of a Package.swift with an executable or a xcodeproj using a package while being in the same repo as the package?

Comment: Both? Would really appreciate seeing an example package that you’ve gotten working that also build a binary which uses the package contents. As above, imagine a framework package but I also want to be able to build and work in a demo executable that uses the framework.

Comment: Also just realized: given your approach which is to basically include a separate project in the repo and then locally use the package in the project (yes?) wouldn’t this be a problem for someone to easily include the package in their own project (since it has the embedded Xcode project along with it)?

Comment: I’ll get those put together. As for the embedded Xcode project question. We have been using this with some new packages we have been making where I work and it hasn’t caused any issues though we only have an executable in those projects. If those also had framework targets it might cause problems? I will have to check that as well.

Comment: Sorry for the delay on posting this example (moving is a pain). I have updated my answer at the bottom to have a link to a GitHub repo with an example project.

Comment: Excellent! I'll give it a try tomorrow.

Comment: Super helpful (and easier than I would have thought). Coolest aspects: 1. That the Package.swift file doesn't need to be updated. 2. That having a nested demo project inside the package dir doesn't affect the use of the package in other projects. 3: That this structure isn't standard because working in the demo project allows for easy development of the package code while being able to test it in the demo app.

Comment: Might be helpful to others if you could repost your Readme from your Git project here.

Comment: The clue `the Package.swift and Example.xcodeproj cannot be in the same directory` was extremely helpful to me!!! My Xcode kept crashing until I made this change - you're awesome!

Answer (score 39):

Here are the steps that worked for me on Xcode 13/14/15-beta:

1. Create a package called `MyLibrary`

[image]

2. Create a new Project App `MyLibraryDemo` inside the package directory

[image]

3. Open the project's `.xcodeproj` file
4. Go to `PROJECT` > `MyLibraryDemo` > `Package Dependencies` and press the 'plus' symbol

[image]

5. Press `Add Local` and select the directory containing your pacakge

[image]

6. Go to the app's `TARGET` > `General` > `Frameworks, Libraries and Embeded Content`, and press 'add'

[image]

7. Select your package from the list

[image]

8. Now you can import your `MyLibrary` package into your example app, and edit / update your package from within you demo project.

[image]

---

Some Notes:

1. If your package / demo has *other* dependencies, and those other dependencies get updated, you may have to clear `DerivedData` before doing an update
2. You *may* also have to close & re-open Xcode, especially if you've updated dependencies, but it still says "Cannot find package `MyLibrary`"

Comment: thanks, it works on Xcode 13.1

Comment: Thank you I was missing steps 6-7 (linking the package in the target) & was going crazy!

Comment: Is there a way to have the demo app and the framework open simultaneously? If I try to have the package open and the demo app open simultaneously, the compiler for the demo app whines I've got the package open.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand, but I always open the Demo app, and you can edit both the app and the package at the same time

Comment: This worked for me too. Make sure to close the actual Package.swift Xcode project (if you have it open in another window like I did) before you follow these steps, otherwise it won't work!

Comment: Works great with Xcode 14 too

Answer (score 8):

The best approach is to use "Xcode workspace".
How does it work?

**1. Create your artifacts**

Create a directory.

Create an Xcode workspace inside there (Xcode: File: New: Workspace). Then create your library (package), and create your app (whatever type) inside the same directory.

In this step, just place the package and the app in the above directory, and close them immediately.

It should look like this.

[image]

**2. Link your artifacts**

Open your .xcworkspace file.

In the left bottom corner, click "+" sign.

[image]

Select "Add files to *your_workspace_name*", then:

a) for the Demo app

Navigate to the app's directory, select *Your_app.xcodeproj* and hit Add.

b) for the package

Navigate to the package's directory, and select the package directory only. Before hitting Add button, make sure "Create folder references for any added folders" is selected.

[image]

Your entire workspace should look like this now. You can immediately import the library inside your app and you are ready to go.

[image]

Comment: Tried this way, but was unable to access package files in my demo app.

Comment: This worked better than the accepted answer for me. Thank you for sharing it.

Comment: Doing it this way causes the package file to be in a sub dir instead of root, hence you can't import it in another project