# What is the correct way to include Playgrounds in a Swift Package?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5, swift-playground, swift-package-manager

When I publish a Swift Package, I like to include some Playgrounds to show examples of how to use the package. Prior to Swift 5.4, I was able to do this in a relatively straightforward way, but now none of my Playgrounds ever sees the contents of my package module. It doesn't make any sense to me.

I've followed the exact pattern illustrated by Apple's own WWDC videos, which is to have a `Playgrounds/` folder as a peer to your `Sources/` folder, and then just import the package module.

The import works, but the Playground always reports that it cannot find any of the types from inside the module. They are all marked `public`, and as I mentioned before, these used to work just fine.

[image]

This doesn't work for me in **Swift 5.4** or **5.5**, in **Xcode 12.5** or **13 Beta**.

I assume there must be some setting or configuration I am not understanding. Can somebody please explain the best practice here?

For reference, here is one of my simple Swift Packages that has Playgrounds that currently do not work:
https://github.com/dunesailer/Wordsmith

EDIT: It gets even stranger. I have a *different* Swift Package structured what appears to me to be the exact same way, but its Playgrounds work fine. Whaaat? That one is here:
https://github.com/dunesailer/Aesthete

Comment: I noticed that the working repo doesn't have a `.static` library product, but the project which is not working does. Why do you use `.static` in `Package.swift`? Though it looks like removing that doesn't help

Comment: This is not the most polished feature in Xcode. Here is someone elses experience which might be helpful: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/xcode-12.5-playground-access-to-app-types/

Comment: Yes, I was afraid that `.static` item might throw people off the scent a bit, but I already tested removing it. If I recall correctly, I need it there because the package loads several resources from itself in order to work, and those didn't work correctly in projects that used this package without the `.static` spec.

Comment: If you want more help, you could go to the [Swift forums](https://forums.swift.org/), if you haven't.

Answer (score 3):

If you move/ delete the folders `Chemical Names`, `Work Titles` and `Person Names` inside `Playgrounds/`, all the playgrounds work fine. It looks like Xcode doesn't support folders in `Playgrounds/` (/ it's a bug).

So to work around this issue, just put all your playgrounds in the same folder.

EDIT: It looks like this works **inconsistently**. I've submitted a [bug report/ Feedback for Developer Tools in Feedback Assistant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5IJB.png).

---

A longer term workaround is to use DocC (arrived in Xcode 13 beta), which will support more advanced tutorials/ articles in the repo.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestions here for a possible workaround, and your time spent experimenting to see what's going on, but what I'm really looking for is the "best practice" in terms of what is the correct, expected way to do this.

Comment: This seems to be a bug, so to have a better experience, it might be worth submitting a bug report and getting it fixed. There is no expected/ best practice way of fixing this. There are plenty of Xcode and Apple bugs we have to workaround, it is quite unusual when you compare it to any other types of development (Android, browser, NodeJS, Java).

Comment: I've awarded you the bounty, even though we didn't really get to the bottom of it all, since your answer was the closest to what I asked, and because you took the time to submit the bug to Apple.

Answer (score 2):

Use workspace.

(Xcode: File: New: Workspace)

You use it as "container" for both your package, playground (or app target for that matter). The important thing is to add each of these to the workspace by using "Add files to ..." button in the lower-left section of the Xcode, and from there on, open the .xcworkspace file:

1. to edit your package
2. to run playground file.

[image]

[image]

You can follow instructions from here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67580251/13292535

Comment: So if I use this approach, it means I cannot distribute my Playgrounds as a part of my Package. I suppose that is just an expected limitation?

Comment: Is this the officially-recommended approach (best practice) for shipping Playgrounds with Swift Packages? Can you reference a source if so? It seems clean and it makes sense, but it is definitely not obvious, and it means the Playground is not in the actual Package, which is a bummer.

Comment: I tried this, and it doesn't solve the problem, it shows the [same error in Xcode](https://i.imgur.com/dgsaxG2.png). @Sardorbek, you should try using the Wordsmith github repo, not just some example playground.

Comment: Putting your Swift Packages in a Workspace is a *done thing*. No one is going to write a book about it, but if you read the Swift forums carefully, you'll see maintainers of Swift doing this with their projects too. The benefits are that schemes are saved to your Workspace, instead of being autogenerated on every `xcodebuild`/ xcode being opened. And also you can run `xcodebuild` on your Workspace scheme even if you have `xcodeproj` in the same directory (another bug workaround). **It doesn't solve your problem though.**

Comment: How to solve author's problem? I cloned the Wordsmith repo, commented ".static" declaration in the Package.swift, then ran "Xcode: File:Swift Packages: Reset package caches" and close/reopen the package. Repeat several times if the playground doesnt still run. Then the playgrounds magically started running.
It seems some kind of bug on Xcode's part.
Using workspace: it was suggested as an alternative way the author could try to fix his problem. It may or may not solve his problem, but that's why we are here: suggest, help find solution, with a perfect or not so perfect suggestions.

Comment: I appreciate the effort and discussion from both of you. You have both been helpful. It seems that the "right answer" to this question simply doesn't work as intended, and that's where we're stuck!